# White space at bottom of anchor tag

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have an  tag surrounding an image. I have a border set on the div that the  tag is in. I have both margin and padding set to 0 but for some reason my  tag is still about 3 pixels taller than my image. This leaves a bit of space between the image and the border, which destroys the look that I want to accomplish.

What am I doing wrong? I have tested in both FireFox and Chrome with the same results.
Thanks

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The image is `display: inline` so it is treated like a character and sits on the baseline. The gap is caused by the space provided for the descender (which you find on letters like j, g, y and p).

Adjust the `vertical-align` with CSS: `img{vertical-align: bottom}`

Comment: More specifically, `img{vertical-align: bottom}`

Comment: That is exactly what is happening. The issue is resolved if I do `vertical-align:bottom;` or `display:block;`. Which is the better solution?

Comment: Neither is better, they just have different implications. Block elements have line breaking around them and other fun side effects.

Comment: The critical one is setting vertical-align to bottom. 9 years passed after this question asked, but I am still curious on why vertical-align affects the height

Answer (score 15):

`display:block` is sufficient for this, if the element has no siblings.

Comment: Interesting, so the real culprit is the image tag, not the <a> tag.

Comment: That is what David pretty much said, any inline element will have space for descenders. It's the natural behavior.

Comment: both "vertical-align:bottom" and "display:block" will remove "extra white space" at bottom

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and i fixed it by adding to the 'a' tag `display: block;` and `font-size: 0px;`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed mine by adding

```
a {
 display:inherit
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

###### December 2021 Solution

As [announced](https://twitter.com/LeaVerou/status/1473243441123504129?s=20) by several people, css `:has()` selector was implemented. So this issue could be solved for anchors which "has" images as a direct child:

```
a:has(> img) {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

At the moment I am writing this reply, it is only supported by Safari TP but probably [this table](https://caniuse.com/?search=has) will be greener soon.