# Mysterious gap under image appearing

Tags: html, css, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [White space at bottom of anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197601/white-space-at-bottom-of-anchor-tag)

Check out this sample page here..
http://denise.brixwork.com/

For some odd reason, under that pic of that family, there's a gap before the grey border (5px #333) div that contains the image. I removed all margins, paddings etc. and it still wont' disappear. :(

Short of setting a fixed height on the #index_content div, which i don't want in case the image has to be re-sized later (which means double the work for me), how can I remove that gap while leaving it elastic?

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="index_content_container">
    <div id="index_content">
        <img src="http://denise.brixwork.com/images/index_photo.jpg" alt="Real Whistler Living - Real Estate for the Next Generation" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
/* INDEX PAGE SPECIAL CSS */
#index_content_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 970px;
    border: 5px solid #e1bb14;
    left: -20px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#index_content {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    border: 5px solid #333;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#index_content img {
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    clear: none;
}
```

Comment: Whats this `<div class="clear"></div>` for?

Comment: <div class="clear"></div> is a clearing mechanism, veyr common to avoid the containing div (such as one with borders) to collapse to 0 height while content inside is visible. Also serves as a clean & compatible <br /> equivalent for <div>s without having to do extra work.

Comment: Quentin - there's no anchor tag in my HTML whastoever.

Comment: @jeffkee - For "anchor tag" read "some element"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
#index_content img{
padding: 0px;
border: none !important;
margin: 0px;
clear: none;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Bingo. Worked like a charm. So basically i was just missing "display:block;"? The !important; part didn't make a difference omitted or included...

Comment: yes correct, the display:block was what you needed. I just do the !important of use of habit

Comment: Using `!important` is an awful habit.

Answer (score 4):

You only need `display: block` in your `img` tag, nothing else =)

Comment: Could you explain us why ? I am coding for some time now and I never had this problem before... Dont understand.