# Remove extra space after html image

Tags: android, html, textview, whitespace

I'm displaying the `html content` in `android Textview`. I'm facing a strange issue while fetching the html images. After the image embed, an extra space is observed. I Tried what suggested in the below links:

1. http://salman-w.blogspot.in/2012/10/remove-space-below-images-and-inline-block-elements.html
2. [Mysterious gap under image appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057611/mysterious-gap-under-image-appearing)
3. [Remove white space below image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image)

But none of the suggestions worked.

And one strange thing, that I observed is: If i remove the `tag`, and add the text without any tag, then `extra space` disappears.

For example:

```
<div class="img_dv"><div class="img_dv_content"><img id="story_image_main" style="display:block;" src="http://htmlimage.jpg" /><p class="img_dv_Caption">Photo Credit: Sample Image Caption</p></div></div>
```

This gives an extra space after the image.

But in the below code, there is no space:

```
 <div class="img_dv"><div class="img_dv_content"><img id="story_image_main" style="display:block;" src="http://htmlimage.jpg" />Photo Credit: Sample Image Caption</div></div>
```

But I have a separate style for caption. So, I must use a custom view, using which gives an extra space.

I also refered the below link and tried.

1. [How to remove the top and bottom space on textview of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593885/how-to-remove-the-top-and-bottom-space-on-textview-of-android)

And tried the solutions given in this link. But none of them is working.

Below is my custom view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:gravity="top">

    <com.ndtv.core.common.util.views.HtmlTextview
        android:id="@+id/img_caption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/img_caption_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/img_caption_size"
        app:customTypeface="@string/roboto_light"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line_below_caption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/img_caption_color"
        android:visibility="gone" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how I'm setting the text to the textview:

```
  public static void createImageCaptionView(Context context, LinearLayout container, String source, Fragment fragment){
        if (context != null && container != null && fragment != null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View imageCaptionView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.img_caption_view, container, false);
            HtmlTextview imgCaption= (HtmlTextview) imageCaptionView.findViewById(R.id.img_caption);
            View lineBelowCaptiin=imageCaptionView.findViewById(R.id.line_below_caption);
            imgCaption.setHtmlFromString(Utility.decodeString(source),context);
            lineBelowCaptiin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            container.addView(imageCaptionView);

        }
    }
```

I'm I doing anything wrong here?. I'm not getting whether it's an `textview` issue or `html` issue or my `layout` issue. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `TextView`s only support a **limited subset** of HTML tags, and aren't really the best View to use for displaying HTML. Use a `WebView`, instead.