# Image inside link tag

Tags: html, css, web

Hi i am creating a website while placing brand logo inside link tag at top right of web page i encountered this problem

```
       <a href="#" >
          <img src='img.png'>

       </a>

       img {
           height: 50px;
           width: 50px;
         }
```

The result is ***a tag*** the wrapping image height is actually **more than 50px** even though there is no text in ***a tag*** . But when i give ***font-size:0*** it Works .

So I need the reason what causes the link tag to take more height.

Please help me understand this concepts rather than just with some css codes

I have sample its . please help me with this .

http://jsfiddle.net/amerrnath/TLBEx/

Ok Sorry i got the answer from the link .

[White space at bottom of anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197601/white-space-at-bottom-of-anchor-tag)

Thank you

Comment: change the vertical-align of the image to `top`: the default is in fact `baseline`. A previous search on SO could have been useful

Comment: vertical-align for anchor tag had no effect .Still same result .
Image is 90px;a is 94px height

Comment: `display: block;` your image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197601/white-space-at-bottom-of-anchor-tag

Answer (score 17):

Change the `img`s `display` to `block`

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
}
a img {
    display:block;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLBEx/2/)

So what does it do? The image inside the link has a default `display` of `inline-block`. The a you set to `display:inline-block`. It's the combination of the two in combination with whitespace inside the `a` element, that does the problem.

You can simulate with two nested `inline-block` `div`s which has the dimensions set only on the inner one. http://jsfiddle.net/TLBEx/4/

Comment: It works even i give font-size:0 but i need concept going on it