# link is under the image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem using link and img because there is a small space in link.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="gridgallery">
    <figure><a href="../img/1-1.jpg" data-caption="Golden Gate Bridge">
    <img src="../img/thumbs/1-1.jpg"></a></figure>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.gridgallery figure {
    background: #fff;
    margin:0px;
}
.gridgallery figure img {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width:100%;
    opacity: 0.95;
}
#gallerytitle {
    width:950px;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0px auto 15px auto;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/33h4ypab/1/

[image: WHY????]

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: No, if I put { display: block; } the a will became height like the img but the small space still stay there

Comment: DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/33h4ypab/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y6dmz9ha/3/)**

```
.gridgallery figure img {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width:100%;
    opacity: 0.95;  
     display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is {display:block;} in {.gridgallery figure img}.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.gridgallery figure img {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width:100%;
    opacity: 0.95;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the approved answer in this question:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/3197601/white-space-at-bottom-of-anchor-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197601/white-space-at-bottom-of-anchor-tag)

Set the attribute `vertical-align:bottom` of the image (no need to change height/width or display:block, ...)

Comment: No, {display:block;} is the right way because I have to create a hover effect for a fluid gallery and {display:block;} run very well

Comment: Did you even try the vertical-align change before saying this solution is wrong? Also I think that believing that it "is the right way to do it ... because it works" is not the kind of mindset a developer should have

Answer (score 0):

```
.gridgallery figure img {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width:100%;
    opacity: 0.95;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```