# css - remove white space below anchor tag

Tags: css, reactjs

See if i can get it working here: https://codepen.io/canovice/pen/pVoBXJ

I have searched a bit for this answer but have had no luck resolving the issue. Here is a screenshot of an anchor tag in a react component of mine:

[image]

Notice the 3px margin (orange) and 3px padding (green), and also notice that below the text is a massive amount of white space that I would like to get rid of, but am struggling to do so.  Any help is appreciated.

*Note: I've tried the suggestions [at this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197601/white-space-at-bottom-of-anchor-tag) with no luck...

*Edit: let me know if theres more i can share on my app, ie. the current stylings, that will help.

**Javascript for the React component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import FaTwitter from 'react-icons/lib/fa/twitter';

import './TopPageHeader.css'

const TopPageHeader = () =>

    <div className="top-page-container">
        <a href="/">Canova's Analytics Dashboards</a>

        <div className="social-links">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/SmokeyCanova">
                <FaTwitter />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

export default TopPageHeader;
```

**and CSS:**

```
.top-page-container {
    padding: 15px 20px;   
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.top-page-container a {
    /*display: block;*/
    /*height: auto;*/
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    /*padding: 15px 0px;*/
    color: #000;
}

.top-page-container .social-links {
    font-size: 1.75em;
    /*padding: 15px 0px;*/
}
```

Lastly, here's what the component looks like on the top of my page. Canova Analytics Dashboard is not centered, but rather offcenter up a bit (due to this extra white space below the anchor tag)... Ideally, the vertical center of the text, and the vertical center of the twitter logo, would both be vertically centered on the div they are contained in.

[image]

Here's what the component is contained within...
This is a top page header component, and hence nothing before it. I don't think the css is being impacted anywhere else, but i could be wrong.

[image]

Comment: do you have any code we can look at?

Comment: Show the HTML code. Because maybe inside a `div` you have an `h1`

Comment: it has been added, and some of my efforts to make this work are showing / commented out

Comment: What element is `top-page-container` contained within? `<body>`? Do you have any rules for that?

Comment: other than the css i've included (which is the TopPageHeader.css) file, I don't think so - will share screenshot of my react div structure up to this header.

Comment: Better yet, create a Fiddle that illustrates the problem.

Comment: i can make a codepen link

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: No worries, I made one myself quickly, and I've posted a suggested answer.

Comment: The extra white space is causing by the `social-link` el

Comment: yes just noticed this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `flexbox` on your `.top-page-container` element, with a `min-height`. This is then correctly forcing the child element to occupy the full container height.

Add the `align-items` property of `.top-page-content` with something like `flex-start`, `center`, etc.

```css
.top-page-container {
    padding: 15px 20px;   
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    align-items: flex-start; // <-- add this
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.top-page-container a {
    /*display: block;*/
    /*height: auto;*/
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    /*padding: 15px 0px;*/
    color: #000;
}

.top-page-container .social-links {
    font-size: 1.75em;
    /*padding: 15px 0px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="top-page-container">
    <a href="/">Canova's Analytics Dashboards</a>

    <div class="social-links">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/SmokeyCanova">
            <FaTwitter />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I'm using `flexbox` for horizontal spacing, not vertical spacing? I tried changing justify-content and it didn't update anything.

Comment: Removing flexbox entirely removed the extra white space, so i think this is on the right track

Comment: I think its align-items

Comment: resizing the twitter icon is giving me issues as well (not shown in the codepen)

Answer (score 1):

Play with the `line-height` CSS property.

For example set it to 1 or 0.

<strike>You haven't provide any example code though.</strike>